# Spring-mvc Rest request header checker

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, header

I should check for each REST request whether the header contains a valid sessionId or not.
Best way to do this I thought would have been adding a simple annotation to each method insede the controller haveing than something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
@CheckSessionId(isSessionIdValid = true)
public String test() throws NotFoundException {
...
}
```

Then i've the annotation interface like this:

```
@Target(value = { ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER })
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
public @interface CheckSessionId {
  boolean isSessionIdValid() default false;
}
```

Then I've implemented the resolver:

```
@Component
public class CheckSessionIdHandler implements HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler,    HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
  ...
}
```

And added inside the servlet dispatcher:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:argument-resolvers>
       <bean class="com.to.my.package.CheckSessionIdHandler"/>         
  </mvc:argument-resolvers>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

But when the "test" method is fired, it never gets inside my annotation.
Any tips?

Comment: Why would this be an argument resolver? You have no parameters and therefore no arguments.

Comment: Use AOP or implement a `HandlerInterceptor`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, with argument-resolver component you won't get near to what you need. A simple interceptor would do though, something like

```
public class CheckSessionInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CheckSessionIdHandler checkSessionIdHandler;

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
 //        ...
        return checkSessionIdHandler.checkSessionValid(request);
    }


}
```

and simply bind it to desired URI patterns

```
   <interceptors>
        <interceptor>
            <mapping path="/*" />
            <beans:bean class="org.example.mvc.interceptors.CheckSessionInterceptor"></beans:bean>
        </interceptor>
    </interceptors>
```

Of course, if you follow this approach you CheckSessionHandler would not need to implement any iterfaces